# Why are Centos 7 kernel updates not flagged as security updates?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a Centos 7.2 box. If I run a "yum check-update --security" command, I get...

```
...
--> kernel-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 from updates excluded (updateinfo)
--> kernel-tools-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 from updates excluded (updateinfo)
--> kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 from updates excluded (updateinfo)
...
1 package(s) needed for security, out of 196 available

epel-release.noarch                      7-9                              extras
python2-rsa.noarch                       3.4.1-1.el7                      epel
```

Why aren't the kernel-* packages being flagged as security updates? What can I do to include them?

Here's my /etc/yum.conf file

```
etc]# cat yum.conf 
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
```

Comment: CentOS doesn't flag _any_ updates as security updates.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Well as you can see in the "yum check-update --security" output, it DID flag the python2 package as a security update. Subsequent "yum update --security" then installed ONLY that python2 package.

Comment: Those are not CentOS updates, they are EPEL updates. EPEL _does_ flag updates as security updates.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh I see now, and the output indeed shows that too.